# Is there an isBlank() like utility for char array to be used for storing a password

Tags: java, java-security

`StringUtils` has the `isBlank()` method. Does `char[]` have something similar that consolidates checking empty, null and whitespace(s)?

Comment: Probably easiest just to create a string.

Comment: Unless the reason you are using a `char[]` is to store a password, in which case you should *not* convert it to a `String` unless you're not concerned about heap hacking.

Comment: This is indeed for storing a password and for the reason stated by @RealSkeptic

Comment: Then why do you care that the characters are blank? Other than checking for null, I assume you are immediately passing it to comparison or hashing or whatever to check the password, or to a test for strength of password. Why do you care if it's empty or consists of blanks?

Comment: @RealSkeptic I don't want to process the password if it contains blanks. It seems to be a password policy best practice.

Comment: Not really. A best practice is to check password strength (at the time of generating passwords). A password of blanks would be rejected by any password strength test. If it's not generation time but just verification time, then it doesn't matter - it's the wrong password, and when you compare it to the real password (or rather, compare its salted hash to the real password's salted hash), it will fail. There is no need to do a special case for it.

Answer (score 4):

There is nothing build in for this specific check but you can write one yourself. The `StringUtils.isBlank()` trims the `String` which you probably want to avoid and instead check the array directly:

```
public static boolean isBlank(char[] arr) {
  if (arr == null) {
    return true; // StringUtils.isBlank() returs true for null String
  }
  for (char c : arr) {
    if (!Character.isWhitespace(c)) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```